# How to take pictures in the dark with an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

The flash on my iPhone 4s works great at night. Problem is the picture is completely black up until the point the flash goes on and the picture is taken. So I don't know if I've got a good shot. Much worse is that it's **always** completely out of focus because the camera doesn't seem to have time to focus during that flash of light.

How do I take night pictures?

Comment: Which solution did you take? Not all answers includes using the flash before taking the photo ...

Comment: I never found a good solution. I don't remember trying the suggestions from @Mehper below, maybe those would work. I now have the latest iPhone and Apple seems to have solved the problem by lighting up the room with the flash first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some apps that may help you with dark night photos (though I have no experience with these apps). Here you are:

1. [NightCap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nightcap/id486414195?mt=8): This app captures 15x more light to capture the best photos in low light situations. It also provides the best tools to help take the perfect shot day or night.
2. [Camera Flash and Zoom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera-flash-zoom/id336356918?mt=8): A full featured camera app with digital flash, 5x digital zoom, geotagging, preview before saving, quick and burst modes, and plenty more tools for night photography.
3. [Night fast Snap!](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/night-fast-snap!/id429360913?mt=8): Very suitable for night photography, you can take 30 clear photos in 2 seconds in the case of low light. The app only fires the shutter when it detects the iPhone is steady to ensure sharpness.

Comment: Never tried these, but seems like the apps would help

Answer (score 1):

Well, one idea is to use the video section of the camera, turn on the light, then take a screenshot ( & then crop out the borders if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [CameraProFx](https://itunes.apple.com/app/zhao-xiang-ji-zhuan-ye-xiao-guo/id602601326) - a free (with adds) paid without adds app which allows to set up the exposure of your iPhone camera so that you can take photos in the dark.